# Select a single record from a priority based list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Apologies if the title is confusing, i'm finding it hard to put into words exactly what i'm looking for. If someone can point me in the correct direction or if another question exists, letting me know would be much appreciated.

If I have the following values in a table I wish to write a query that selects a single record for each `[ContactID]`.

The query should check first if a record exists with `[PhoneType]` 'Mob' then **-->** 'Work' then **-->** 'Hom' and return the first record that matches and ignore the other records for the `[ContactID]`

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [ContactID] int,
    [PhoneNo] NVARCHAR(20),
    [PhoneType] NVARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #Test
(
    [ContactID],
    [PhoneNo],
    [PhoneType]
)
VALUES
    (1, '51351301', 'Mob'),
    (1, '999', 'Work'),
    (1, '8461', 'Hom'),
    (2, '213231321', 'Work'),
    (3, '848136', 'Mob'),
    (4, '23231', 'Hom'),
    (4, '2132315', 'Work')
```

The result would look like

```
(1, '51351301', 'Mob'),
(2, '213231321', 'Work'),
(3, '848136', 'Mob'),
(4, '2132315', 'Work')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by contactid
                                order by (case when phoneType = 'Mob' then 1
                                               when phoneType = 'Work' then 2
                                               when phoneType = 'Hom' then 3
                                               else 4
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from #test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you have a separate table with contacts, you can also use `apply`:

```
select t.*
from contacts c cross apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from #test t
      where c.contactid = t.contactid
      order by charindex(phonetype, 'Mob,Work,Hom')
     ) t;
```

Note that this uses a shorthand for the ordering.  This will work for your phone types -- but assumes these are the only three.

Comment: Thank you, that edit is relevant to me, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Use `window function` with *top(1)* with ties

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH ties *
    FROM #Test t
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contactid
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN phoneType = 'Mob' THEN 1
                                            WHEN phoneType = 'Work' THEN 2
                                            WHEN phoneType = 'Hom' THEN 3
                                            ELSE 4
                                            END)
                                   )
    )D
ORDER BY D.ContactID
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and edit.

Is there any benefits of using the `top(1) with ties` over Gordons answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want.  It sets a row ID for each `ContactID`, and only pulls the first one for each `ContactID`

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [ContactID] int,
    [PhoneNo] NVARCHAR(20),
    [PhoneType] NVARCHAR(20)
);

--DROP TABLE #Test

INSERT INTO #Test
(
    [ContactID],
    [PhoneNo],
    [PhoneType]
)
VALUES
    (1, '51351301', 'Mob'),
    (1, '999', 'Work'),
    (1, '8461', 'Hom'),
    (2, '213231321', 'Work'),
    (3, '848136', 'Mob'),
    (4, '23231', 'Hom'),
    (5, '2132315', 'Work')


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY PhoneType ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM #Test
    WHERE PhoneType IN ('Mob', 'Work', 'Hom')
) Sub 
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

If you want to get specific phone type first you can use this select statement for ronum

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY  CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'Mob' THEN 1 WHEN PhoneType = 'Work' THEN 2 WHEN PhoneType = 'Hom' THEN 3 END ASC) AS RowNum
FROM #Test
WHERE PhoneType IN ('Mob', 'Work', 'Hom')
```